# Why Lodash wrapper doesn't work with forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, wrapper

I came across this when updating chained lodash manipulations and I don't understand why it would work differently

I narrowed it down to chaining a forEach on a lodash wrapper

```
let tab = [{a:1, b:1}, {a:1, b:2}, {a:2, b:1},{a:2, b:2}]
let res = _(tab).forEach(el => {el.c = 3; return el;}).groupBy('a')
console.log(res)
```

https://jsbin.com/wahokezeja/edit?js,console

This will throw an error:

> "TypeError: _(...).forEach(...).groupBy is not a function

However when chaining with a map it works fine

```
let tab = [{a:1, b:1}, {a:1, b:2}, {a:2, b:1},{a:2, b:2}]
let res = _(tab).map(el => {el.c = 3; return el;}).groupBy('a').value()
console.log(res)
```

https://jsbin.com/mofusel/1/edit?js,console

It has something to do with _(tab).forEach returning an array rather than the lodash wrapper, but don't see why it happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lodash forEach does not behave exactly like the JS forEach, but nor is it exactly like map.  `_.map([1,2,3],a=>2*a)` will return an array `[2,4,6]` as you might expect, however `_.forEach([1,2,3],a=>a*2)` returns `[1,2,3]`. It is intended to perform an operation per array element (like the JS `[].forEach`) but it does not return a modified array, rather it returns the *original* array as a convenience.  If you want to modify an array then use `map`.

Try the following:

```
var arr=[1,2,3]; 
var rslt=_(arr).forEach(v=>v*2); 
console.log(arr===rslt);
```

and you can see that it returns true - the 'result' from the forEach, wrapped or not, is just the original array.

After digging into the lodash code, and some helpful comments from @VLAZ, the key to understanding this is the lazy evaluation associated with the chaining (which is the point of the array wrapping referred to above).  The (wrapped) chained methods enable lazy evaluation.  If you call `_(array).map(fn1).map(fn2).value()` then the evaluation does not take place until the value method is called.  This is a good efficiency improvement as (in this case) only one output array is generated (unlike the standard JS map method will cause intermediate arrays to be generated after every step).  However `forEach` is different - it requires immediate execution, and so it ends the chain.

Comment: It seems intentional - [it's documented](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#lodash): "*The wrapper methods that are **not** chainable by default are: [...] forEach [...]*". Actually, I was surprised that `_.forEach` returns a collection, I was under the assumption it didn't. So, to me, it made perfect sense that `forEach` will end a chain, since it would *normally* be a terminal operation, similar to `reduce`. Although I guess that even if `_.forEach` returns a collection normally, you can't chain it effectively, since the operations are normally lazy but `forEach` doesn't fit.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, just reached the same conclusion after digging into the underscore code.  The chaining is for lazy evaluation and, for expacted behaviour reasone, `forEach` must terminate that chain.